# Telerik Rad Grid Data Display Issue in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I've created user control in asp.net which has Telerik Rad Grid. Currently I'm using Telerik 2012 version. Problem, grid data is getting disappeared in a fraction of seconds only in IE 10 version. When I clicked on view source of page data does exist in page but in UI it will not visible. But in other IE version grid data is getting displayed properly. Please do reply if anyone has come across such scenario and solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is too old to support IE10, so it is likely you have JavaScript errors or other imcompliances that cause the entire layout to break.

To fix it upgrade your Telerik controls to, at least, something at the end of the year (i.e., after the IE10 release), but I advise the latest (Q2 2014).

Also, have a look at this on common JS problems with IE10 and .NET 4 that are caused by .NET but can break your entire site: http://www.telerik.com/forums/javascript-errors-in-ie10-and-the-site-is-working-fine-in-the-rest-browsers.

This may also be interesting on treating the same problem with IE11: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11.